# Помогите разобраться с сокетами, а точнее с http протоколом

Tags: c, сокет

Пытаюсь написать свой, простой web сервер

```
#define HOST "127.0.0.1" 
SOCKET Start_Server(short port) 
{ 
      WSADATA                wsaData; 
    SOCKET                Winsock; 
    struct sockaddr_in    Winsock_In; 
    struct hostent        *Ip; 
    char                hn[1024];

    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData); 
    Winsock=WSASocket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP, NULL, (unsigned int)NULL, (unsigned int)NULL); 
    if(Winsock == INVALID_SOCKET){ 
        WSACleanup(); 
        return -1; 
    }

    Ip = gethostbyname(HOST); 
    Winsock_In.sin_port = htons(port); 
    Winsock_In.sin_family = AF_INET; 
    Winsock_In.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(HOST);//inet_addr(inet_ntoa(*((in_addr*)Ip->h_addr_list[0]))); 
    if(bind(Winsock, (SOCKADDR*)&Winsock_In, sizeof(Winsock_In)) == SOCKET_ERROR){ 
        WSACleanup(); 
        return -1; 
    } 
  return Winsock; 
}

void Main_WebServer() 
{ 
    SOCKET                Winsock; 
    char                Buf[255]; 
    char*                temp; 
    char                buf[255]; 
    char*                buffer[255];  
    struct sockaddr_in client;  
    int clientsize = sizeof(client);  
    int i;

    Winsock = Start_Server(5656); 
    listen(Winsock, 5);

    strcpy(Buf, "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n"); 
    strcat(Buf, "Content-Type: text/html\r\n"); 
    strcat(Buf, "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");

     while (1) 
    { 
        int s; 
        FILE *f;

        s = accept(Winsock, (struct sockaddr*)&client, &clientsize); 
        if (s == INVALID_SOCKET) break;

        send(s, Buf, (int)strlen(Buf), 0);

    }

    closesocket(Winsock);  // закрытие сокета  
    WSACleanup();  
}
```

Если через netcat подключаться к 5656, то при подключении выводятся заголовки, которые по идеи должны отправиться в браузер.
Но когда пытаюсь обратиться через браузер localhost:5656, то браузер просто пытается загрузить страницу, и будет загружать до тех пор, пока не отключу сервер. Т.е. такое ощущение как будто зацикливается, что-то где-то.
Помогите разобраться пожалуйста.

Comment: Самое простое - Разрывайте соединение с клиентом после отправки нужного текста. так реализовано в проколе http 1.0

Comment: Молодец, продвигаетесь.

1). Проверяйте успешность вызова Start_Server().

2). WSACleanup лучше не вызывать вообще, чем дважды. Были прецеденты каких-то ошибок, связанных с этим.

3). Обдумайте, как будете обрабатывать **несколько** одновременно пришедших (s = accept(...)) соединений - через thread-s или используя select().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так понятное дело зависает. Браузер не может узнать, что данные закончились не успев начаться. Он читает заголовки и ожидает, что вы будете сейчас слать данные, а вы этого не делаете. Укажите Content-Length (например, 0), либо используйте chunked-mode. Либо сами закрывайте сокет s после отправки данных.

PS: И вот ещё: что за rn? Достаточно просто n.

Comment: _PS: И вот ещё: что за rn? Достаточно просто n._ Вообще, по [спецификации](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2) - CRLF.